# How do I resolve avoid duplicate symbols in common transitive Xcode dependencies?

Tags: modularity, dll, xcode4.4

I have the following Xcode project dependencies:

```
A -> C
B -> C
```

When I build these separately, everything works fine.

However, I want to add `A` and `B` to the same Xcode project, creating the following dependency graph:

```
    / -> A -> C
D-<
    \ -> B -> C
```

This causes duplicate symbol errors, and is basically DLL hell.  What is a good way to resolve this while allowing the projects to be independent?  I realize that I could break up `A` and `B`'s dependency on `C`, and then remake that dependency in `D`, but I want `A` and `B` to be indpendently buildable.

Answer (score 1):

In A and B's project files, remove C from 'Link binary with libraries' while leaving it in target dependencies.  This allows you to use C in A and B, but not to use C in D.  To use C in D, add it directly to D (don't count on A or B passing it down).

Comment: But then, I can't build and use A or B independently. Consumers of A or B need to know to add C as a dependency.